Clicking an invisible checkbox using Selenium Python
I have a problem with clicking checkboxes in a site. I had a working script that found checkboxes and later clicked them, but now the site had an update and the elements are different. The checkbox elements are invisible until the mouse is hovered over them (same as before). I have no idea why it doesn't work with the new elements: I tried all of them.
Here's a snippet of the old working code that saved the information about the checkboxes:
    for element in doc_elements:
        classes = element.get_attribute("class")
        tid = element.get_attribute("tid")
        logging.info(f"Processing element with classes: {classes} and tid: {tid}")

        if "iconic _b-letter-document-row__checkbox-label" in classes:
            checkbox_id = element.get_attribute("for")
            previous_checkbox = checkbox_id
            logging.info(f"Found checkbox for future document: {checkbox_id}")

I don't need to click them for now, as I have a function that clicks them (hoping that it will work as it used to). I just need to get the element for the checkbox.
Here's the code for selecting the checkboxes:
def select_all_checkboxes(page, documents):
    if not isinstance(documents, list):
        logging.error("Expected a list of documents, but got something else.")
        return []

    clicked_checkboxes = []  # To track clicked checkboxes

    for doc in documents:
        if not isinstance(doc, dict):
            logging.error("Document is not a dictionary. Skipping.")
            continue

        # Ensure required keys exist in the document dictionary
        if 'name' not in doc or 'checkbox_for' not in doc:
            logging.error(f"Document is missing required fields: {doc}")
            continue

        checkbox_id = doc['checkbox_for']
        document_name = doc['name']

        try:
            logging.info(f"Attempting to select checkbox for document: {document_name} with checkbox id: {checkbox_id}")

            checkbox_label = page.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"label[ft-name='checkbox-label'][for='{checkbox_id}']")

            page.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';", checkbox_label)
            page.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display='block';", checkbox_label)

            page.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", checkbox_label)
            logging.info(f"Checkbox selected for document: {document_name}")

            clicked_checkboxes.append(checkbox_id)

        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            logging.error(f"NoSuchElementException: Checkbox not found for document '{document_name}'. Exception: {e}")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Exception: An error occurred while selecting checkbox for document '{document_name}': {e}")

    return clicked_checkboxes

I tried having the program hover over an element so that the element for the checkbox becomes visible, but that didn't help: It just hovers over every one, but it never saves the data for the checkbox id.

Can you provide link to the actual site?

what waits have you used with the hovering? https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/

i can provide the link to the actual site but it has a login form
<diadoc.kontur.ru>
and i tried this wait:
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=2)
wait.until(lambda d : revealed.is_displayed())
the last time it worked i used just javascript to click the checkbox but now i cant make it work again.

@DanielKhairetdinov That's too bad. Have you attempted getting the required data directly from the backend if possible?

No, i wouldnt even know how to approach that, like what am i asking for and how do i use it? i have no idea how that works. an example would be really helpful :)
